# Spark Dataframe, how to filter GPS rows based on distance threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, outliers

Iam tring to define the good approach to filter rows in a dataframe of GPS position with a distance threshold.

First i calculate the distance with an UDF by using a lag.
I was wondering how i can do that without recalculating a second time the distance after filtering the first one  which is superior of the threshold.
And do over again the UDF calculting distance.

```
Input
 |-- device_id --|-- gps_point --  |-- date  -- |
 |       1       | latlongvalue 1  | 2000-01-01 |
 |       1       | latlongvalue 2  | 2000-01-02 |
 |       1       | latlongvalue 3  | 2000-01-03 |

OutPut
 |-- device_id --|-- gps_point --  |-- date  -- |-- distance_covered --|
 |       1       | latlongvalue 1  | 2000-01-01 |            0         |
 |       1       | latlongvalue 2  | 2000-01-02 |         10000(error) | 
 |       1       | latlongvalue 3  | 2000-01-03 |         10300        |

Desired output 
 |-- device_id --|-- gps_point --  |-- date  -- |-- distance_covered --|
 |       1       | latlongvalue 1  | 2000-01-01 |           0          |
 |       1       | latlongvalue 3  | 2000-01-03 | X km (from GPS1 to 3)|

val dfDeviceGpsEvents = gpsEvents.join(devices, Seq("device_id"), "left")

val dfDeviceWindow = Window
              .partitionBy("device_id")
              .orderBy($"device_id", $"date_gps")

val DfwithDistance = dfDeviceGpsEvents
        .withColumn("gps_point", convertToMagellanPointUDF($"real_gps"))
        .withColumn("prev_gps_point", lag("gps_point", -1, null)
          .over(dfDeviceWindow)
        )
        .withColumn("distance_covered",
           when($"prev_gps_point".isNotNull,
                computeHaversineDistanceUDF($"gps_point", $"prev_gps_point"))
          .otherwise(lit(null))
        ).withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

What I am trying to code :

```
var loopError = 1
while (loopError > 0){

//get the first row in the DF with distance > to the threshold and get the index
   val rowToFilter = firstWithDistance.select("idx").filter($"distance_covered >" + threshold).first()
      if (rowToFilter.size > 0) {

        // filter out the row of the DF
        firstWithDistance = firstWithDistance.filter("idx ===" + rowToFilter.get(0))

        loopError = 1
        //redo the distance calculation with lag over all the DF
        firstWithDistance = firstWithDistance
          .withColumn("next_gps_point", lag("gps_point", -1, null)
            .over(deviceWindow)
          )
          .withColumn("distance_covered", when($"next_gps_point".isNotNull, computeHaversineUDF($"gps_point", $"next_gps_point"))
            .otherwise(lit(null)))
      }
      else {
        loopError = 0
      }
    }
```

Comment: In order to answer this question we need more detail. Can you please provide example input and output? What code do you currently have?

Comment: I updated my description

Comment: Please also provide sample input and output (does not have to be real data but must resemble the real data), it is not clear from your description

Comment: any idea or comment ?

Comment: @JonathanMyers I updated my description with some "pseudo code" not yet tested but it seems really ugly to loop over a DF like that